# Customize neo4j web interface saved scripts

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am running multiple neo4j databases and I am using saved scripts, customized to respective db, to accelerate manipulations.

An issue: the browser store scripts based on the IP+port (127.0.0.1:7474) which is the same for all databases, and I ends up with one set of saved scripts for all databases.

Any solution to bind saved scripts to a corresponding database?

Comment: We are working on a cloud based solution for this. Otherwise it should also work to use different ports for your different databases.

Comment: Thanks Michael, it works.
Indeed I have changed the port on the server configuration file 

"neo4j-server.properties"

# db1 : 
org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474

# db2 : 
#org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7475

# db3 : 
#org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7476

Comment: another idea might be using different browser profiles for each instance.